# How to Simplify safely

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-form

Mathematica often writes simplied expressions with `-1` first followed by any variables (eg. `-1+x`).
However I want to write it as  `-(1-x)` i.e. retaining `1-x` form everywhere.
The reason is two fold: first is of course beautification. Secondly sometimes when multiplying a number of expressions containing some parts in the numerator and denominator differ by overall negative sign do not simplify unless I use `FullSimplify`. Now sometimes using `FullSimplify` at a later stage of simplification could be considerably inefficient in terms of performance.

Some naive custom simplification rules to cure this problem could be dangerous as the following toy example:

```
t1=(-((-1+u) /(1+u (-1+v))))^(-(1/2))//PowerExpand
```

[image]

Now this is not nice looking. A naive delayed substitution could be fatal.

```
t2 = (( t1 /. Plus[-1,x_] :> (1-x)*$g ) //PowerExpand)/. {$g->-1}
```

[image]

This is of course wrong.

**How should one safely do such simplification to force `(1-x)` form correctly?**

Edit:
The desired form of the input (restricting in a unit hypercube) will look like following:

```
 t0=(-((-1+u) /(1+u (-1+v))))^(-(1/2))
```

[image]

```
 t3=Assuming[{0<=u<=1,0<=v<=1},t0 /.  Power[x_,y_] :> Simplify[Expand[x]]^y /. {Plus[-1,x_] :> (1-x)*$g} /. {$g->-1}]//PowerExpand
```

[image]

Note that `t0` and `t1` differ by `PowerExpand`. So the results differ if I first do Simplification within brackets and then PowerExpand or first do PowerExpand and then do simplification.

Comment: Use `TraditionalForm` for **display**: `(t1 = (-((-1 + u)/(1 + u (-1 + v))))^(-(1/2)) // PowerExpand) // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Sorry I corrected a mistake in the question `x-1` is not I am after rather `(1-x)` form.

Comment: Did you evaluate the code that I posted?

Comment: Yes of course  :D .  It is giving `u-1`. I want to write everyting in the `1-u` form. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As long as we stay with real number this is not wrong. `I` in the numerator is canceled by `Sqrt[-1]`in the denominator.

Comment: @DanielHuber, yes you are right. But as I said, beautification is also a priority along with efficient simplification. I wanted to say the second graphics is wrong where I do a naive delayed replacement just to keep the `1-x` form everywhere.

Comment: I'm confused—the second image, which you get from naive delayed replacement, is algebraically correct for real numbers. I think the problem for complex numbers only comes with having to choose a branch for `Sqrt`, which must be done manually anyway. It also only uses the form `1-x`. Is it nonetheless still problematic somehow?

Comment: @thorimur you are missing a subtle point. My intention is to keep (1-x) form throughout. The second image is algebraically WRONG. Notice that there should NOT be an overall negative sign.

Comment: @thorimur, if I restrict `u,v` in a unit hypercube, shouldn't the input expression `t1` (NOT the images) be evaluated to give `(1-u(1-v))^(1/2) /(1-u)^(1/2)` ? That is to say that the expression within the brackets will be evaluated first and then it will do `PowerExpand` ?

Comment: No, I think it's algebraically correct: a `Sqrt[-1]`, which is `I`, is introduced in the denominator, which cancels the `I` in the numerator: `I/I == 1`. So the overall negative sign is preserved. Try `Plot3D`ing both `t1` and `t2`: they overlap! :)

Comment: @thorimur, output of first two graphics are correct. Please see the Edit of the question where the same expression is evaluated in the desired form of graphics-3. I think all the problem comes due to `Power` `-1/2`. I think now I  expressed the problem clearly. Its about which operation in done first, simplification within brackets or PowerExpand.

Comment: @thorimur, please see the Edit part of the question. The expressions `t0`, `t1` are having same input form (if you ignore the overall PowerExpand of `t1`). Now if I first do `PowerExpand` and then `Simplify`  then it takes an overall negative sign. But if I first simplify the expression inside the bracket (as in `t3`) and then do `PowerExpand`, it does not have the overall negative sign. Now if I assume `u,v` to be in unit hypercube, the output of `t3` is the correct one which somehow does not follow from `t1` or `t2`.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. `t1` and `t2` are indeed numerically equal in the unit square, e.g. `t1 /. {u -> 0.6, v -> 0.2}` is equal to `t2 /. {u -> 0.6, v -> 0.2}`; but the `PowerExpand` in `t1` flips the sign, you're saying, so `t1` is wrong. (I thought you were saying `t1` and `t2` were unequal). Interesting...

Comment: @thorimur, my bad. I think its the similar problem of convention. That is one should first evaluate `Brackets` and then others. So in order to simplify if I blindly do `PowerExpand`, `Simplify` that could be wrong?. Basically it seems that the use of `PowerExpand` has to be done carefully. That is why I asked `Safely` :D

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `PowerExpand` being, well...questionably implemented! The "Possible issues" section of `PowerExpand` notes that it will sometimes do weird things under automatic assumptions. If you know that `u,v > 0`, you can do `PowerExpand[t0, Assumptions -> {u > 0, v > 0}]` and get the right answer. You can also do `PowerExpand[t0, Assumptions -> {}]` for maximum safety and generality, but you get an ugly sign factor in front. In general idk...but either way `PowerExpand` seems responsible for your woes here! I wonder if `Simplify` by itself could be made to work...

Comment: Yes I thought the `Simplify` and `PowerExpand` could do no harm. But it seems like I have to follow what you said i.e. while using `PowerExpand` one has to be careful. This is just a toy example, I am sure in reality people will encounter complicated expressions where it will be difficult to debug these issues.

Comment: @thorimur, is there any way to make `PowerExpand[t0, Assumptions -> {}]` default so that I can simply use `t0//PowerExpand` . Btw you could consider converting your comment as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is beyond the expression that OP uses to illustrate the problem. Namely, indeed, sometimes the internal order used by Mathematica differs from the wish of the user to present an expression.

As much as I know from experience, this typically happens in two main cases.

1. The main reason is to represent the result in an easily readable form after the calculations have been finished. In this form, the expression is less prone to errors when rewriting it into another document.
2. As a second reason, one may need to make terms easily visible before applying operations requiring assumptions such as neglecting some terms in comparison to other ones or expanding parts of the expression in series and alike.

In the first case, the approach of @ Bob Hanlon may be effectively applied.

Here I would like, however, to share a function that makes the job without transforming the expression to TraditionalForm. The advantage is that if you do it in the middle point of your transformations, you can continue the calculations in the StandardForm.

The function factorMinus[expr, fun] takes minus out of the expression.
Arguments:

expr is the expression in which one needs to take minus out.

fun is the optional function applied to the expression left after it has been multiplied by -1. By default it is Identity.

```
factorMinus[expr_, fun_ : Identity] := (-1)*HoldForm[Evaluate[fun[(-1)*expr]]]
```

Basic example:

```
factorMinus[-1 + x]
```

[image]

In more complex cases, one has to map this function onto the parts of the expression where one wants to take minus out.

Do not forget that prior to making further calculations with Mathematica one should apply `ReleaseHold` to the resulting expression.

Have fun!